# Angular routing without changing location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-app

[Chrome Packaged Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/apps/about_apps.html) have a rather strict Content Security Policy. One result of this is that manipulating the location (like clicking on a link) results in:

```
'Can't open same-window link to "chrome-extension://lkjasdfjklbdskjasdfjkhfdshjksad/derp.html"; try target="_blank". '
```

Target _blank will open the link in chrome which is not what I want. Can AngularJS' routing work in such a locked-down environment?

They docs give [an example](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/apps/angular_framework.html) of an Angular app, but conspicuously does not use routing.

**Update**

Here is the link that, when clicked, gives the error: `<a class='walrus-link' ng-href='paystubs/{{walrus.id}}'>Walrus {{id}}!</a>`

Comment: Just a sanity check: are you using Angular 1.1.0+ instead of 1.0.x? And can you post the code for your $routeProvider that is giving you trouble?

Comment: yep I am on the latest (1.1.3)

Comment: You ever get this figured out?  I've never looked into Chrome packaged apps until I saw this. Curious to see how you're getting along.

Comment: After much effort, your answer was the correct one. It seems you must explicitly change $location yourself and then Angular will route correctly. I think Google doesn't want packaged apps to be too similar to traditional websites, but there are adjustments when web developers come in with certain practices from the web (e.g. links)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using an href, try using ng-click and call a method to your controller the relocates to the appropriate page using $location.  See the documentation on the [AngularJS site](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location).  The following quote from the doc gives an indication that the $location service might be appropriate for you:

> When should I use $location? Any time your application needs to react
>   to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current
>   URL in the browser.

Your code might look something like this:

```
<a class='walrus-link' ng-click='getPaystub(walrus.id)'>Walrus {{id}}!</a>
```

and in your parent controller, you'll need a scope method called 'getPaystub' with a line similar to:

```
$scope.getPaystub = function(selectedWalrusId) {
  $location.path('paystubs/'+$scope.walrus.id);
}
```

This way angular keeps control and won't cause a page refresh.  This hopefully keeps you within the bounds of the CSP.  Unfortunately I cannot test this in a packaged app, but I've used the exact same convention in a web app and it works just dandy.

Answer (score 0):

routing works for me in my chrome app when not using $routeProvider's html5 mode (which is disabled by default), you just have to use a hash in the url.

so my links look like this:

```
<a href="#about">About</a>
```

$routeProvider configuration is as follows:

```
$routeProvider.when('/about', {templateUrl:'about.html'})
```